# Storing pictures AND a profile picture in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, database, photo

I am trying to make a page where the user has his own photos but also his own profile photo. I am uploading the actual photos to a file server then inserting the photo names into a MYSQL Database. So my table so far is,

**photos**

-photo_id

-photo_name

-user_id

So how do I declare a photo as a profile photo? What is the common method? Do I create a different table?

Comment: Why not just add a foreign key to your user table, eg `profile_photo_id`? Then it can link to any photo

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what other photos are in that same table it might make sense to put profile photo filenames in a separate table or to create another column in your table for a boolean  photo_type.  Read up on [designing data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_design) and [normal forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).